# Volley 1.1 dependency on org.apache.http

Tags: android, android-volley

as I understand from here https://github.com/google/volley/wiki/Migrating-from-Apache-HTTP **volley 1.1 dropped mandatory dependency on org.apache.http**. And

> "Most apps using HurlStack or Volley#newRequestQueue with
>   minSdkVersion set to 9 or higher should not need to take any action
>   other than removing the useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' declaration from your build.gradle file if it is present."

I don't use org.apache.http anywhere but when I try to do `Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext())` or new `HurlStack()` on a unit test I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/StatusLine
```

during runtime. Checking the HurlStack class I see it inherits from BaseHttpStack which clearly still depends on org.apache.http

```
import org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine;
```

**So, I didn't get it, am I supposed to include org.apache.http if using volley with api level > 23 or not ?**

Workaround:

If I include this to build.gradle the tests run fine:

```
testImplementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5"
```

Note:

This is not a generic question about NoClassDefFoundError, it regards specifically to Volley throwing this exception when the instructions (read link on the post) says it shouldn't.

Comment: What are you using for unit testing?  Mockito?  RoboElectric?  Junit4 or 5?  It's possible the test framework is for some reason defaulting down to a lower minSDK verision, thus forcing the need for Apache HTTP.  If that is the case, put a manifest in your testing folder that sets the minsdk higher.

Comment: Note; You can't use volley from a non-instrumented unit test on Android - see https://github.com/google/volley/issues/346

Answer (score 4):

Use below line in AndroidManifest file in Application tag for Android Pi(9) devices

```
  <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
```

Comment: You should explain why this is the solution :)